# how many max loopbacks can i have?

Tags: linux, v4l2loopback

How many loopbacks are possible with v4l2loopback-dkms?

Can i only have 8 loopbacks using modprobe v4l2lookback devices=8, any more and it seems to be capped at 8.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of devices is hardcoded in [the source](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/blob/v0.12.5/v4l2loopback.c#L162):

> ```
> /* maximum number of v4l2loopback devices that can be created */
> #ifndef MAX_DEVICES
> # define MAX_DEVICES 8
> #endif
> ```

and a [kernel message](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/blob/v0.12.5/v4l2loopback.c#L2393) (usually visible using `dmesg`) is generated if trying to use more when the module is loaded:

> ```
>   if (devices > MAX_DEVICES) {
>       devices = MAX_DEVICES;
>       printk(KERN_INFO "v4l2loopback: number of devices is limited to: %d\n", MAX_DEVICES);
>   }
> ```

In case this limit isn't depending on an other limit (eg: due to the V4L2 framework), you can consider recompiling the kernel module, probably using a package named `v4l2loopback-dkms` or anything else adequate providing sources depending on the Linux distribution in use, with a changed value for `MAX_DEVICES`.